# React- D3 PieChart API integration using axios in class component (how to fetch the data)

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, render, pie-chart

How to fetch the data?

Here's my Component Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import axios from 'axios'
import ReactD3 from "react-d3-components";
var PieChart = require('react-d3-components').PieChart;


//dummy data from d3 
var data = {
  label: 'something',
  values: [
    { x: 'SomethingA', y: 10 },
    { x: 'SomethingB', y: 4 },
    { x: 'SomethingC', y: 3 },
    { x: 'SomethingD', y: 3 },
    { x: 'SomethingE', y: 1 }
  ]
};


//tooltip
var tooltipScatter = function(x, y) {
  return "x: " + x + " y: " + y;
};
var sort = null;

class UsersByDevic extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/data')
      .then(response => {
        console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", response.data);
        this.setState({
          data: response.data.pie_chart,
        })
        console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@", this.state.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("CHECK ERROR", error)
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        { data.length 
          ? data.map(data => <div>
            <PieChart
              data={data}
              width = {500}
              tooltipHtml={tooltipScatter}
              height={500}
              margin={{
                top: 10,
                bottom: -200,
                left: 100,
                right: 100
              }}
              sort={sort}
            />
          </div>
        ) : null
      }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

UsersByDevic.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string
};

export default UsersByDevic;
```

`data = {this.state.data}` gives the following error:

> TypeError: data.map is not a function

Am unable to fetch the data in the `render` method

This is data need to fetch using `axios` method

```
{
  "pie_chart": [
    { "label": "Equity", "value": 300 },
    { "label": "Real-estate", "value": 270 },
    { "label": "Debt", "value": 230 },
    { "label": "Bullion", "value": 180 },
    { "label": "Insurance", "value": 20 }
  ]
}
```

Am getting errors:

> 1.TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined pie
>   E:/TASK/template/react-material-dashboard-master/node_modules/react-d3-components/node_modules/d3/d3.js:6633
>    6630 | d3.layout.pie = function() {
>    6631 |   var value = Number, sort = d3_layout_pieSortByValue, startAngle = 0, endAngle = τ, padAngle = 0;
>    6632 |   function pie(data) {
>   6633 |     var n = data.length, values = data.map(function(d, i) {
>          | ^  6634 |       return +value.call(pie, d, i);

or

> Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of data that you're getting from the API is not in the format that a [**`PieChart`**](https://github.com/codesuki/react-d3-components#piechart) component expects.

You will have to format the data that you're getting in this format:

```
{
  label: 'Cost Distribution',
  values: [
    { x: "Equity", y: 300 },
    { x: "Real-estate", y: 270 },
    { x: "Debt", y: 230 },
    { x: "Bullion", y: 180 },
    { x: "Insurance", y: 20 }
  ]
}
```

Once you have the format in place and you've set the `data` with this format, you'll also have to change the condition that you have in your `render` method:

```
render() {
  const { data } = this.state;
  return (
    <div>
    {
      data 
      ? <div>
          <PieChart
            data={data}
            width={500}
            tooltipHtml={tooltipScatter}
            height={500}
            margin={{ top: 10, bottom: -200, left: 100, right: 100 }}
            sort={sort}
          />
        </div>
      : null
    } 
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pie-chart-eg-jkaw3c) for your ref.

Comment: thank you for your help, Working Sample Demo shows: Error in /turbo_modules/d3@3.5.17/d3.js (6633:20)
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. so initialized data = [ ]  in constructor   through error like TypeError: data.map is not a function

Comment: @sandhyashrinivas, I think there was an issue with the my changes not reflecting. I've updated the answer with the correct StackBlitz link. I've verified that it works as expected now. Please have a look. And sorry for the issues. :)